# Google Refine does not recognize match

Tags: regex, openrefine

Using Google Refine, I'm trying to add a column based on the current column.

The current column contains url params, e.g.

> q=how+to+match+google+refine+string&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=sb&gfe_rd=cr&ei=wpFCU-PfDZDd8gektIGoAw

How can I add a column for the `q` key?

Currently refine just gives me `null` when I try something as basic as:

> value.match('/q/')

***Update:***

I managed to get the key:

 `'.*?(ip=).*?'`

But I'm looking now to get the value to the key. Either till the end of string or next '&'

Answer (score 1):

`match()` performs matching over the whole string. So try with these two:

```
.*q.*
```

or using a word boundary `\b`:

```
.*\bq\b.*
```

Comment: That does not work. I realised now the regex is Java's Pattern.

Comment: This fixed my problem, though. Thanks @sabuj-hassan!

Answer (score 0):

`value.match('.*?(q=)([^&]*).*?')[1]`

gives

> how+to+match+google+refine+string